# What is the meaning of 去不去的 as in 去不去的问题?

Tags: translation

I encountered at an online database for Chinese example Sentences:

> 在去不去的问题上徘徊不定

So far, I understand the elements of the sentences as follows:

徘徊不定 is the predicate of the sentence, made up of the verb 徘徊 (to hesitate) and its complement 不定 ("not determined"), therefore it should mean sth. like "to hesitate without comming to a conclusion".

在去不去的问题上  is the adverbial of the sentence, made up of the preposition 在...上.

My problem within the sentence is the part: **去不去的** 问题, the characters used are very common ones, but nevertheless i do not know what meaning is beeing conveyed by their construction. When I try to translate it verbatimally, i get stuck with: "go-or-not-go-problem", what is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 3):

Your instinct is right: it literally means to go or not to go. So the guy couldn't make up his mind to go (somewhere, need context) or not.

Comment: great, so it is verbatim about going to some place, not whether the problem is a problem that is possible to solve?

Comment: @meireikei Yes.